# Django 1.9 web page doesn't redirect or change

Tags: python, django

I checked other pages to figure it out and I looked [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) but couldn't find a solution to this.

When I click to change the page from navbar nothing happens. homepage is extends to the header.html but others are not. infact when I click to another button change the page it stays still. here are my codes;

home/first/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'first/home.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'first/iletisim.html', {'content':['Eger bizimle iletisime gecmek isterseniz mail adresimizi kullanabilirsiniz.', 'gulumhali@outlook.com']})

def home (request):
    return render(request, 'first/home.html')
```

home/first/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^home/', views.index, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name = 'iletisim'),
]
```

main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('first.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

SOLUTION:

Like Adam said below; if you having this problem change the order home/first/urls.py for views.index.

Comment: Try moving your index to the bottom of your urlpatterns?  It should check the urls in order, so it's probably matching that one first.

Comment: That was smart. That worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first URL is catching everything. Essentially it's saying if the URL has a start to it, send to index.

Since it's the first url in the list, it's always going to catch that first since it goes through the url patterns and finds the first one it matches. As you've found out in the comment, if you move it to the bottom, when you go to either `home/` or `contact/` it will catch those first.

However, you still will have a problem with that because if you go to `asdfblahblah/` or anything, it's still going to catch that. What you should do is add a `$` to show that there should be nothing in the URL to route to index. That regex says if there is a start, and an end, and nothing in between, route to index.

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^home/', views.index, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name = 'iletisim'),
]
```

Comment: I wanted to stay that way because if someone types and extra thing I still want them to see the home page. I did that deliberately. Other then that do you think there will be a problem with my action? Thank you for your answer in general it could help people.

Comment: Nope, shouldn't be a problem then if you want all URLs that aren't listed to go to the index view.  Just make sure that all URLs are listed before the catch-all - including your other apps you include.